# Take something from upstair or from downstair

Tags: word-usage, word-request

what is the correct daily english when we want to get someone to "take something from upstair or from downstair or from high position". Can we say " Hi Dear, can you please help to **take** "something"down from the room/upstair" or " Hi Dear, can you please help to **bring** "something"down from the room/upstair"? As I know "Bring Down", "Bring Up" , "take down" and "Take up" has it meaning, for example : Bring Down - To cause the failure or defeat of someone or something.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just because something is also an idiom as a set phrase or phrasal verb, doesn't mean it can't be used literally.

In the specific scenarios you describe, I would use ***take*** when it is going away from the location of the speaker and/or listener, and ***bring*** when it is coming towards the speaker.